# How can I keep my popup focused?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have created a couple of pages whose content will be displayed in a pop up window.
I have a page where I define 3 links:

```
<a href = "page1.htm", onClick="window.open(this.href,'content','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, left=70,top=20, width=900, height=900,innerWidth=900, innerHeight=900'); return false;">Page1</a><br />
<a href = "page2.htm", onclick="window.open(this.href,'content','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, left=70, top=20, width=900, height=900,innerWidth=900, innerHeight=900'); return false;">Page2</a><br />
<a href = "page3.htm", onClick="window.open(this.href, 'content',' scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, left=70, top=20, width=900, height=900, innerHeight=900, innerWidth=900'); return false;">Page3</a>
```

When clicking on the link, I have a popup displayed. But when clicking on another link, the popup is minimized. I need to keep it opened and display appropriate content from another page.

Unfortunately, I cannot use any `javascript` functions to `focus` my popup, since I need to put the links onto another vendor's website, that allows only simple `html` to be copied over, so when someone else will click the link, popup will open appropriate content.

Is there any way to achieve that with what I currently have?

Comment: What do you mean by *simple html*? You already use in-line JavaScript. Is it OK?  What about `<script>` tags inside HTML file?

Comment: simple html is just <a href..../> in that case. Inline javascript should be ok too

Comment: Even if your vendor allows just html files, you can still have client-side JS in them.  I suggest you get more information on what the actual limitations are.

Comment: I don't think you can control the window focus of popups on another domain... can you??